# U-SQL Python Reducer __init__.py already exists error

Tags: python, u-sql

The first time I run a U-SQL script containing a Python reducer, it runs successfully:

> "Completed with 'Success' : 2/9/2018 3:06:12 PM"

The second time I run a U-SQL script containing a Python Reducer I receive this error:

> "An unhandled exception from user code has been reported when invoking the method 'Constructor' on the user type 'Extension.Python.Reducer'","description":"Unhandled exception from user code: \"The file 'C:\Users\ThomasHepner\...\Debug\TestScripts\IrisNulls\XDRReader\__init__.py' already exists."

If I go to the folder path and delete the *IrisNull* folder, I can rerun the U-SQL script successfully, without error.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem without manually deleting the folder containing the **init.py** file?

Comment: sounds like you are creating two files in your code. If so, check the existence of the file before creating it again.

Comment: Is this in local run or cluster run?

Comment: This is a local run.